# Druid Groupby: druid's groupby considering only 1000 records per group to aggregate Average

Tags: group-by, druid

I was calculating average of each group. Noticed that average it is calculating only for 1000 values per group instead of considering the complete data points.

Trying to calculate Average time taken for each cycle

Query:

[image: ''' SELECT "cycle" AS "cycle", AVG("time") AS "AVG(time)", COUNT(*) as "Record_Count" FROM "edadata" GROUP BY "cycle" ''']

Query Explanation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Results:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

druid uses approximations by default, for faster, pretty accurate results.  The TopN query type indicates it's doing an approximation.  If you click the three dots next to "Run" and disable "Use approximate TopN", I think the explain will show a groupBy query, and it should use all the data (but be slower).

Answer (score 0):

its easy just click on next to Run .
Disable " Limit Inline Results " and execute the query.
But if you have records in lakh then it may through exception